# Automatically check for column width beyond 72

Tags: syntax, fortran, warnings, lint

So I kind of inherited this (not really legacy) project written in Fortran. In order to make it thread-safe, I had to pass a `void*` pointer (called `user_data`, you might know the pattern) to all fortran routines so they could pass it back to the callbacks (hence global state was properly heap allocated now).

To my sincere surprise, this lead to a complete breakdown and segfaults in the weirdest places. After all, I had only added one unchanged argument to all functions?

To my sheer horror (I am not a Fortran programmer, just an average hacker with a knack for problem solving), I learned that a Fortran compiler simply ignores everything beyond column 72, probably because columns are expensive or something, without even giving a warning (well except for some cases where a "type error" (haha type-discipline in Fortran, what a joke) was reported).

Up until today I keep finding places in the code that suffer from the  unintended consequences of this indention.

Is there any tool out there that can check a Fortran codebase reliably for this kind of mistake?

And, as a bonus question dedicated to John Oliver: Why is a 72 column limit still a thing?

Comment: Anonymous downvoter: Could you please provide a comment about why that question is bad?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but was very tempted to do so. Not only because of the language of your post, but also because of your lack of research. Fixed-form Fortran is indeed a bit tricky (that's why it was superseded by free-form more than 25 years ago), but Fortran compilers are generally very well documented. One look into the manual of your compiler would have solved your problem.

Comment: BTW: Fortran compilers can very strictly enforce type compliance (and do so as you have noticed yourself). In fact, almost any recent guide on Fortran advises you to use `implicit none` which will remove any any implicit typing at all.

Comment: 72 column limit has not been a thing for 25 years since Fortran 90 introduced free source form. Read some tutorial from this century.

Comment: sure but converting old fixed source to free form isn't quite a trivial matter.  If you are editing old code and don't want to convert to free form you should use an editor that will flag stuff beyond col 72.  As to why not just discard the old standard you should realize some old source used the space beyond 72 for comments and such.

Comment: Back in the olden days... before eclipse, vi, nedit and emacs... There were cards. The cards were about 8-1/2" wide, and could hold 80 characters, so 72 for code and some extras for comment (I think). Sometime in the 70s we got terminals and CRTs. So were are ~25 years progressed from f90. (If we assume F90 is is subtracted from 2013...) But I think 1990 was the conception of F90 and the gestation took awhile. Still is was all grown up before F03, and later....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any tool out there that can check a Fortran codebase reliably for this kind of mistake?

Yes, your compiler. With `gfortran`, this would be `-Wline-truncation` (included in `-Wall`, something that you always should have on). With `ifort`, this would be `-warn truncated_source`. I would bet that (almost) any other compiler has options for this as well.

The column limit of 72 is grown historically from punch cards and kept for backwards compatibility. With most compilers you can change or even disable this limit. With `gfortran` this would be `-ffixed-line-length-<n>` with an integer `<n>` and `-ffixed-line-length-0` to disable it.